# Nonce fail after second submit attempt

Tags: php, forms, nonce

I am refactoring my plugin that resets the WordPress database tables back to their defaults and came across an issue.

The form submission itself works fine. However, after the first submit, and if you do not refresh the page and submit the form again, the nonce seems to fail. Perhaps there is someone that fully understands how nonces work as I am not sure what is causing this.

I have the necessary check for `wp_nonce_field` and `check_admin_referer` on the administration side.

As I can't post specific parts of the code, here is the link to the refactored (WIP) plugin:

https://github.com/chrisberthe/wordpress-database-reset/tree/refactoring

Comment: Does the URL change after the first submit? Are the URL parameters different?

Comment: I don't see where you're setting the current admin page in your form?

Comment: I didn't add it as it just sets the action to the current page if you omit it. If I do something like `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ?>"...` it still has the same effect.

Comment: You need to, otherwise how does WordPress know to load your page rather than the standard tools page without the necessary URL parameters

Comment: It's strange. Like I said even if I do add that to the form action it yields the same results. If what you're saying is correct, it wouldn't work the first time the form is submitted; but it does. And anytime you refresh the page after that. It's only when you submit the form, and submit it again without refreshing that it throws what seems to be the nonce error.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 % positive but my understanding is that a Nonce expire as soon as you use it. It can only be used for one transaction. So it seems to be logic that it expire after the first call.

You should probably return a new one with the response of your first validated request and replace it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wikipedia seems to agree with me ;-)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce

Comment: WordPress nonces are (confusingly) **not** "only once" - they just have [a limited lifetime](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)